# check if second li element has current class

Tags: html, jquery, css

on blog page i am showing list of block items using `grid-column: 1 / -2;` in first row i am showing two items, stretching first blog item to two columns and then showing the second items and rest of the rows show 3 items in each row. screenshot will give you a better idea. this works fine but when i switch to second or 3rd page it still show the same first row as its while i only want to show the latest blog stretched in two columns and rest of the pages should show 3 columns in first row.

A way around that i found in the pager control by check if `current` class in in second element.

Now my question is how can i detect using jQuery if Ul LI element has `current` class in second element, if it has then i will change the `grid-column: 1;` so that it will show 3 columns in first row if its on 2,3,4 or 5th .... page..

[image]

my pager control code is as below

```
<ul id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_pnlPager" class="nav-pager">
<li><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_-1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PagerControl1$-1','')"> « </a></li>
<li><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PagerControl1$0','')">1</a></li>
<li class="current"><span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_39e9e1f727784cce80f1a3b5e6e43ac0">2</span></li>
<li><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_2" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PagerControl1$2','')">3</a></li>
<li><a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_26" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PagerControl1$26','')"> » </a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried below code which is for testing only to see if it works, this simple code is not working. in this i am trying to change background color ..

```
if($("ul li").hasClass('current')) {
  $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
  }
```

Comment: Do you _need_ JQuery?

Comment: I am looking at jQUery if same is possible with css then even better..

Comment: Something like `$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_PagerControl1_pnlPager li").eq(1).hasClass('current')`

Comment: @CBroe, i tried something like `if( $(".nav-pager li").eq(1).hasClass('current'))
 {
 $(this).css("font-size", "40px");
 }` it doesnt change font size for test purpose

Comment: I’m guessing `$(this)` probably doesn’t refer to what you think it would (depends on the context in which you actually execute this code.) Use a simple `console.log` statement instead, and then check what the browser console shows.

Comment: @CBroe, found a work around `$(document).ready(function(){
var ctr = 1;
  $('.nav-pager li').each(function (){ 
    if($(this).hasClass("current")){
          $(this).css("color", "red");
          console.log(ctr);
          if (ctr = 1)
          {
          alert("Found : " + ctr);
          }
    }
    ctr = ctr +1;
  });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Solved : using jQuery i display two items in first row of first page and 3 rows in all the pages

**CSS**:

```
.article:nth-child(1) {
   grid-column: 1;
}
```

**jQuery Part**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var ctr = 1;
        $('.nav-pager li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass("current")) {
                if (ctr == 2) {
                    //  alert("Found : " + ctr);
                    $(".article:nth-child(1)").css("grid-column", "1 / -2");
                  
                }
            }
            ctr = ctr + 1;
        });
    });
```